# Multi threading with a list of input in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, list

I am totally new to multithreading. I am try to work on a simple test
I have a list of number from 1 to 100. The function I want to multithread is simply a function to multi the number by 5 then console.writeline the result

class Program
    {
        public static List data = new List();
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().run();
            foreach(int d in data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(d);
            }

```
    }
    int multiply (int a){
        return 5 * a;
    }
    void run()
    {
        int threadCount = 5;
        Task[] workers = new Task[threadCount];

        Task.Factory.StartNew(consumer);

        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
        {
            int workerId = i;
            Task task = new Task(() => worker(workerId));
            workers[i] = task;
            task.Start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Queueing work item {0}", i);
            inputQueue.Add(i);
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Stopping adding.");
        inputQueue.CompleteAdding();
        Task.WaitAll(workers);
        outputQueue.CompleteAdding();
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    void worker(int workerId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is starting.", workerId);

        foreach (int workItem in inputQueue)
        {
            int b= multiply(workItem);
            data.Add(b);
            Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is processing item {1}." ,workerId,b);
            Thread.Sleep(100);          // Simulate work.
            outputQueue.Add(workItem);  // Output completed item.
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is stopping.", workerId);
    }

    void consumer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Consumer is starting.");

        foreach (var workItem in outputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Consumer is using item {0}", workItem);
            Thread.Sleep(25);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Consumer is finished.");
    }

    BlockingCollection<int> inputQueue = new BlockingCollection<int>();
    BlockingCollection<int> outputQueue = new BlockingCollection<int>();
}
```

Comment: What is the questions?

Comment: Try reading this http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: I have a list of number from 1 to 100. I want to make 5 threads running the same method . The method is simply multiply it by 5 and print it out in C#

Comment: This is quite basic. There are plenty of tutorials online. Have you looked? Do that then have a go. If you have problems then post the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: I want it to have worker and consumer

Comment: Is there a website like stackoverflow for dummy. I barely know anything

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're asking?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) { list.Add(i); }

        foreach (int value in list)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => PrintNumberTimesFive(value));
            thread.Start();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void PrintNumberTimesFive(int number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number * 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want it to have a worker and consumer . Thanks though

Comment: What if I want to store the data somewhere? and how can I control the number of thread. For example I want to have 5 threads running